# Two inequalities displaying side by side, but nicely spaced in LaTeX

Tags: latex

In LaTeX, I have two ineqaulites e.g. a \leq b and c \leq d. I want to have a numbered line which has both of these inequalities on it:

```
a \leq b      c \leq d     (1)
```

Like this. What's the easiest way to get the spacing to behave itself? Which environment should I use?

Comment: (but with more space between the "b" and the "c". That'll teach me not to study the preview before posting...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is, of course, to use the `amsmath` package. A perhaps less-known feature of the `align` environment is to place equations side-by-side, exactly as you are trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &\leq b   &   c &\leq d     
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

And if you add multiple lines they'll look good:

```
\begin{align}
a &\leq b   &   c &\leq d  \\   
a+1 &\leq b+1   &   c+1 &\leq d+1     
\end{align}
```

Which is the whole reason, really, for not using `\quad` and other manual spacing commands.

Comment: Indeed a less-known (or less-consciously-known) feature of `align`: it takes care of the intercolumn space which is, of course, what we're after in this question. +1

Answer (score 5):

For *some* space, just use `\quad`, `\qquad` or any other spacing command of your choice (maybe `\hfill`?).

I don't know about any environments to do this, the environments that come with the AMS packages are meant to align columns (so they're only useful if you have multiple lines).

Comment: `align` also aligns multiple equations on a single line. Add more `&`. (And see `alignat` for more flexibility.)

Comment: Of course it does; but it does not really matter, because there is only one line (like making a one-row table). Adding more `&` is like using a `table` instead of `div`'s in HTML: abuse of semantic constructs in order to improve formatting. If you want to use AMS environments, `align` or `alignat`, do *not* insert more `&` just for spacing.

Comment: You mean you *shouldn't* write something like `a&=b &&& c&=d`? Well, depends what you're doing :) The `amsmath` environments aren't very semantic anyway. I'd argue, however, that using a single `&` to separate equations is more "semantic" than using `\qquad` but if `\qquad` looks better for a particular case then go for it.

Comment: I agree on `&` being more semantic than `qquad`, therefore I upvoted your answer; my remark on being semantic or not was about the use of *multiple* `&`'s for one intercolumn space.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `amsmath` package (for spacing options). The do the following:

```
\begin{equation}
a \leq b \qquad c \leq d
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Actually, there's no amsmath here: \qquad is standard.

Comment: `amsmath` does however contain the `align` environment, which you'll probably end up wanting if you're doing anything very fancy.